# What command should I use to request ocsp status

Tags: openssl

I have deployed basic ocsp server from `OpenSSl Cookbook` by Ivan Ristic page 44 with following command

```
$ openssl ocsp -port 9080 -index db/index -rsigner root-ocsp.crt -rkey private/root-ocsp.key -CA root-ca.crt -text
```

Certs have following chain `root-ca -> root-ocsp` and `root-ca -> sub-ca -> server`

```
 $ openssl verify -CApath server.crt sub-ca.crt root-ca.crt                                                        sub-ca.crt: C = GB, O = Example, CN = Sub CA
error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate
root-ca.crt: C = GB, O = Example, CN = Root CA
error 18 at 0 depth lookup:self signed certificate
OK
```

I think it is right

And I want to request status of `server.crt`.

```
$ openssl ocsp -issuer root-ca.crt -issuer sub-ca.crt -CAfile root-ca.crt -cert server.crt -url http://127.0.0.1:9080
Response Verify Failure
140042325554840:error:27069070:OCSP routines:OCSP_basic_verify:root ca not trusted:ocsp_vfy.c:166:
server.crt: unknown
        This Update: Mar 27 13:19:09 2017 GMT
```

What I am doing wrong?

```
$ ll
total 96
drwxr-xr-x 2 bjorn users     4096 Mar 24 11:19 certs
drwxr-xr-x 2 bjorn users     4096 Mar 24 11:19 db
-rw-r--r-- 1 bjorn wireshark 3160 Mar 19 13:08 ocsp_recording.pcapng
drwxr-xr-x 2 bjorn users     4096 Mar 24 10:56 private
-rw-r--r-- 1 bjorn users     2542 Mar 24 11:03 root-ca.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 bjorn users      934 Mar 17 21:50 root-ca.crl
-rw-r--r-- 1 bjorn users     6876 Mar 17 21:39 root-ca.crt
-rw-r--r-- 1 bjorn users     1732 Mar 16 14:29 root-ca.csr
-rw-r--r-- 1 bjorn users     5747 Mar 19 10:09 root-ocsp.crt
-rw-r--r-- 1 bjorn users      948 Mar 17 22:07 root-ocsp.csr
-rw-r--r-- 1 bjorn users     5103 Mar 24 11:19 server.crt
-rw-r--r-- 1 bjorn users      980 Mar 24 11:03 server.csr
-rw-r--r-- 1 bjorn users     2436 Mar 16 14:11 sub-ca.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 bjorn users     6682 Mar 17 22:03 sub-ca.crt
-rw-r--r-- 1 bjorn users      928 Mar 17 21:58 sub-ca.csr
```

[Whole project zip](http://dropmefiles.com/tB7VU) (everywhere password is `pass`)

Comment: `root ca not trusted` is what it is saying

Comment: @schroeder but I have included root in -CAfile, can you give me a command that you think is right?